# How to make a app using sails js + a vue js template?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, sails.js

First, i came from a PHP + CSS background, where i used to simply put the CSS files on header and JS on footer -- you know, classic stuff.
Now, I`m trying to make a system using Sails JS as backend and a Vue JS template as frontend. I have no idea how to make this guys "talk to each other".

Please, I appreciate any help.

My best.

Comment: Have you taken a look at this project: https://github.com/ndabAP/vue-sails-example?

Comment: Hi, I will try it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Right on the point:**

1. Put the `.js` files in your `assets/js` folder and your `.css` in `assets/css`.
2. By default Sails inject in your `layout.ejs` all source files - styles and scripts - inside `/assets`, take a look bellow for more information. Disable that behavior on `config/pipeline.js`! Now you have 2 choices, use a layout (if you want to serve your `.js` file for all views) or simply put it in the end of your new view like this (remember to save it in the `views/` folder with .ejs and only a body tag inside)`:

```html
 <body>
  <div class="container" id="idforvue">
    Hello!
  </div>
  <!-- vuejs cdn here  -->
  <!-- your js href like '/js/myjs.js'  -->
</body>
```

3. Setup a route for your view! Edit your `config/routes.js` and insert a new line `'/' : { view: 'filename'},`.
4. Do a `sails lift` and access `localhost:1337' to see your changes.

**More infos:** 
First of all, you can use a lot of server-side rendering to solve some problems. Out of the box Sails uses EJS. Take a look [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/views/view-engines). Now you also want to read the Assets docs [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/assets). Dont underestimate this framework, it is awesome! Read the docs carefully and you should be fine...

**EDIT:** github example here: [LINK](https://github.com/paulogdm/sails-example-for-geovani)