# How do I serve a Vue Webpack app from Sails.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, vue.js, sails.js

I have a Sails.js server and a Vue Webpack application running separately. This is what my folder structure looks like:

- `/application-root/server/`
- `/application-root/client/`

The /server/ folder contains my Sails.js application and /client/ contains my Vue Webpack application.

I don't want to host these two separately. I want to be able to just deploy the server and make it such that the server renders the Vue Webpack application. I am aware that Sails uses .ejs as a templating engine.

How do I render my Vue.js application instead of the default .ejs templates that Sails uses?

I tried solutions like [vue-sails-template](https://github.com/steventhanna/vue-sails-template) etc. but they all come with some compromises and pre-existing code that I have to work around. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to run `npm run build` to get a version of the Vue webpack application that is useful to a server side renderer.

I don't know much about Sails, but check out [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46930202/how-to-make-a-app-using-sails-js-a-vue-js-template) to see if that's helpful for the rest.

Comment: The difference between the answer in that question and what I want is that I am trying to use a Vue Webpack app inside Sails, not a generic instance of Vue without Webpack.

Comment: right, that's why you've got to build it. once you run `npm run build`, the dist folder is functionally equivalent to static files that you might put in an assets folder.